# I need the id and name of inner element when cloning a row of a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When hitting **areasensornewline_button**, a new row gets created and appended to the table. I can change the row ID, but all new dropdownboxes within this row now have *id="selectedArea0"*, *id="selectedSensor0"* and *name="AreaBinding0"*, *name="sensorBinding0"*. These have to be 1, 2 and so fort. Any help would much be appreciated!!!!

```
    <table border="0" id="areasensor_table">
        <tr id="areasensor_row0">
            <td id="area_column0">
                <select name="areaBinding0" id="selectedArea0"> @for(area <- areas) {
                    <option value="@area.uniqueid">@area.name</option>}
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="sensor_column0">
                <select name="sensorBinding0" id="selectedSensor0"> @for(sensor <- sensors) {
                    <option value="@sensor.id">@sensor.name</option> } 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="areasensornewline_button"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    <p>
<script>
var q = 1;
document.getElementById('areasensornewline_button').onclick = cloneRowAreaSensor;

function cloneRowAreaSensor() {
    var row = document.getElementById('areasensor_row0'); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById('areasensor_table'); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    var innerClone = row.innerHTML;
    clone.id = 'areasensor_row' + q; // change id or other attributes/contents
    q++;
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick is to use Regular expression but is far to be perfect ...

```
        function cloneRowAreaSensor() {
            var row = document.getElementById('areasensor_row0'); // find row to copy
            var table = document.getElementById('areasensor_table'); // find table to append to
            var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
            clone.innerHTML = clone.innerHTML.replace(/0"/g, q + '"');
            clone.id = 'areasensor_row' + q; // change id or other attributes/contents
            q++;
            table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
        }
```

The added row is placed outside the tbody html tag. You really should use jQuery, il will help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a lot of time :).

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works first time. Create a counter use it to name element.

Example:

```
var count = 1;
for(i = 0; i<= 10; i++){
var row = document.getElementById('areasensor_row'+ count +'');
}
```

It is a simple example. You need to restructure your code like this example. (This cicle for isnt better example, but it works at 10 elements)